# Path Compression , How does this code is path compression?

Tags: java, algorithm

```
/*
* To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
* To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
* and open the template in the editor.
*/
package algorithm1;

/**
 *
* @author Navin
*/

public class QuickUnionWeighted {


private int [] id;
private int [] size;
int numberOfChild;
int j=0;

public QuickUnionWeighted(int N){

    id =  new int[N];
    size =  new int[N];

    for(int i=0;i<N;i++){

        id[i] = i;
        size[i]=1;
    }


}

 public int root(int i){

     while (i != id[i]){
         id[i] = id[id[i]];
         i=id[i];


     }

     return i;
 }   

 public boolean connected(int p,int q){

     return(root(p) == root(q));
}


 public void union(int p,int q){

     int i =  root(p);
     int j = root(q);

//         if(i == j) return;

     if(size[i] < size[j]){

         id[i] = j;
         size[j] += size[i];
     }else{
         id[j] = i;
         size[i] +=size[j];
     }


    for(int k=0;k<size.length;k++){
        System.out.print(size[k]+" ");

    } 

 }


public static void main(String [] args){


    QuickUnionWeighted quw = new QuickUnionWeighted(10);


    quw.union(3,0);
    quw.union(4, 0);
    quw.union(3, 5);
    quw.union(3, 6);
    quw.union(3,9);



}



}
```

Because as I examined the code, the `id[i] = id[id[i]]` is pointing to the parent of the node, and the examined node is not moved to its grandparents and the tree is not flattened.

Kindly Guide.

Comment: I down (and close-) voted this question because it is not clear what you expect this code to do. You might get more help if you give some more explanation as to what you are trying to do with this code, what it actually does and why you don't understand that behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
id[i] = id[id[i]];
```

This line is the path compression. `id[i]` is the parent of node `i`. Hence, this line re-links node `i` to its grand-parent. Therefore, it skips the parent. Then, the same happens to the grand-parent and so on. This flattens the tree.

Here is a visualization of this step:

```
1                    1
^                   / \
|     root(3)      /   \
2    -------->   2       3
^
|
3
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is long due. But in case anyone still needs this.

Just as Nico said, this line is the path compression:

```
id[i] = id[id[i]];
```

But what it does is connect the node `i` directly to its grand-parent. It then skips the parent node, and the whole process is repeated for the grandparent onwards. Thereby flattening the tree.

However, to connect the node `i` directly to the root node, here is another implementation of path compression:

```
id[i] = root(id[i]);
```

This creates a recursive function that goes down to the root node and sets every node on that path to point directly to the root node.

Check https://algorithms.tutorialhorizon.com/disjoint-set-union-find-algorithm-union-by-rank-and-path-compression/ and page 9 of this material https://cseweb.ucsd.edu/classes/sp15/cse100-ab/lectures/Lec17_pdf.pdf